# Devexpress SkinRibbonGalleryBar how to change the whole form (Including frame)

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, devexpress

I have a WinForm, which is using a SkinRibbonGalleryBar to customize the design in runtime.
Now, if I select a skin there, it's applying to the application, but all the frames have the basic windows 7-look instead of a custom design.
How can I set that the frames are going to change their looks too?

Note: Since this is all managed in the Designer, I have **No** Code for this one!

edit: The Frame of the main-form is changing, but not the ones of other forms which are opened by the main one.

edit 2: All Forms are Xtra Controls by Devexpress, it used to work once.

edit 3: The first line of a new form:
    public partial class Information : DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm

Comment: Are your form is `Form` class descendant or `XtraForm` class descendant?

Comment: @nempoBu4 Changed my Post, all Forms are XtraForms

Comment: Can you add the first line of your form code, like: `public partial class Form1 : Form` or `public partial class Form2 : XtraForm`?

Comment: @nempoBu4 added line to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the main-form's frame skinning feature, apply a skinning painting scheme to a form (for example via the DefaultLookAndFeel component) and call the [WindowsFormsSettings.EnableFormSkins](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsWindowsFormsSettings_EnableFormSkinstopic).
To enable the child-form's frames skinning feature for MDI child DevExpress forms, apply a skinning painting scheme (for instance, via the DefaultLookAndFeel component) and, at runtime, call the [WindowsFormsSettings.EnableFormSkins](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsWindowsFormsSettings_EnableFormSkinstopic) and then, the [WindowsFormsSettings.EnableMdiFormSkins](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsWindowsFormsSettings_EnableMdiFormSkinstopic) method.

Typically, this method should be called on the application startup:

```
//[Program.cs] 
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DevExpress.XtraEditors;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8 {
    static class Program {
        /// <summary> 
        /// The main entry point for the application. 
        /// </summary> 
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            //Enable title bar skinning
            WindowsFormsSettings.EnableFormSkins();
            WindowsFormsSettings.EnableMdiFormSkins();

            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

---

Related help-article: [Form Title Bar Skinning](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8436)